# How can I "hide" the data in AWS from users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I want to build an application using Amazon Web Services (AWS).
The way the application should work is this;
I make a program that lets the user import a large file in an external format and send it to AWS (S3?) in my own format.
Next many users can access the data from web and desktop applications.
I want to charge per user accessing the data. 
The problem is that the data on AWS must be in an unintelligible format or the users may copy the data over to another AWS account where I can not charge them. In other words the user need to do some "decrypting" of the data before they can be used. On the web this must be done in JavaScript which is plaintext and would allow the users to figure out my unintelligible format. 
**How can I fix this problem?** 
Is there for instance a built in encryption/decryption mechanism?
Alternatively is there some easy way in AWS to make a server that decrypts the data using precompiled code that I upload to AWS?

Comment: Any reason why the data conversion ("decryption") has to be done in JavaScript? Why can't you use a server-side technology like Java/PHP/Ruby/Python etc?

Comment: Good point. Could the server be on AWS? If so which AWS technology would be easiest to implement? I looked into lambda and it looked promising since it seemed to allow me to easily upload a function. However the speed is critical. The data will be many GBs large and must be decrypted fast. The ideal would be if there was some AWS component that allowed me to upload a compiled C/C++ function that decrypted a S3 record.

Comment: Your question is fairly broad. There are of course many ways to host this as a service on AWS. You could deploy some sort of service on an EC2 server, or you could upload a function to Lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general when you don't want your users to access your application's raw data you just don't make that data public. You should build some sort of server-side process that reads the raw data and serves up what the user is requesting. You can store the data in a database or in files on S3 or wherever you want, just don't make it publicly accessible. Then you can require a user to login to your application in order to access the data.

You could host such a service on AWS using EC2 or Elastic Beanstalk or possibly Lambda. You could also possibly use API Gateway to manage access to the services you build.

Regarding your specific question about a service on AWS that will encrypt your public data and then decrypt it on the fly, there isn't anything that does that out of the box. You would have to build such a service and host it on Amazon, but I don't think that is the right way to go about this at all. Just don't make your data publicly accessible in the first place, and make all requests for data go through some service to verify that the user should be able to access the data. In your case that would mean verifying that the user has paid to access the data they are requesting.

Comment: Thank you for your help mbaird! I read that Elastic Beanstalk supports .net. I guess I could implement a websocket server in C# and upload it to Elastic Beanstalk. The server could use S3 as backend storage.

Comment: Alternatively I guess I could upload an Apache webserver with home made hooks to EC2.

Comment: Just write the service in whatever technology/language/server you feel most comfortable with. You can run pretty much anything on EC2. Use Elastic Beanstalk if you don't want to deal with setting up and managing servers yourself.